# Error "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID" when starting Excel

Tags: excel, powershell, 64-bit

I am running PowerShell on 64-bit machine. The line

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
```

gives the error

```
New-Object : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} failed due to the following error:
80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154
(REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

I researched and tried to run `powershell_ise.exe` from

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```

as explained [here](http://www.tellingmachine.com/post/Help!-My-COM-object-fails-to-load-from-the-PowerShell-ISE-with-error-80040154.aspx), but I still get the error.

Comment: Your version of Office is 64 bit?

Comment: @DavidBrabant, the Windows Server 2008 R2 I am running powershell from doesn't even have office. Once I can generate the file, then I can send it in email

Comment: @DavidBrabant --- if you post your question as an answer I will mark it as a solution, because it gave me idea to install Office

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, here it is then: you have to install Office 64bit.

Answer (score 2):

I installed Office 2007 on the server and it now works